# Images are not showing from json, SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, xcode, image

SwiftUI Code where i using json file to get the data, in this code i am truying to fetch the images from the json file but it is showing error. This error is showing for all the images,  where i using json file to get the data, in this code i am truying to fetch the images from the json file but it is showing error. This error is showing for all the images, :

```
import SwiftUI

struct Property: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()
    let address: String
    let imageName: String
    let thumbnailName: String
    let type: String
    let price: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var properties: [Property] = [] // Placeholder for property data
    @State private var watchList: [Property] = [] // Placeholder for watch list
    @State private var selectedPickerIndex = 0 // Separate @State for picker selection
    @State private var selectedTab = 1 // Separate @State for tab selection
    
    var filteredProperties: [Property] {
        switch selectedPickerIndex {
        case 1:
            return properties.filter { $0.type == "House" }
        case 2:
            return properties.filter { $0.type == "Unit" }
        case 3:
            return properties.filter { $0.type == "Land" }
        default:
            return properties
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            // Properties Tab
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Properties")
                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        // Action to add property
                        // You can implement this action
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3))
                
                Divider()
                
                // Secondary Tabs
                Picker(selection: $selectedPickerIndex, label: Text("")) {
                    Text("All").tag(0)
                    Text("House").tag(1)
                    Text("Unit").tag(2)
                    Text("Land").tag(3)
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .padding(.horizontal, 4) // Adjust padding to reduce gap
                .padding(.bottom, 1) // Add additional padding to the bottom
                .padding(.top, 1)
                
                List(filteredProperties) { property in
                    PropertyRow(property: property)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            // Navigate to property details view
                            // You can implement this navigation
                            print("Navigate to details for: \(property.address)")
                        }
                        .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                            // Add property to watch list
                            if !watchList.contains(where: { $0.id == property.id }) {
                                watchList.append(property)
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Properties", systemImage: "house")
            }
            .tag(1)
            
            // Property Watch Tab
            WatchListView(watchList: $watchList)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Watches", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                }
                .tag(2)
        }
        .onAppear() {
            loadData()
        }
    }
    
    private func loadData() {
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/deepak/Desktop/Property List/properties.json")
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
            properties = try JSONDecoder().decode([Property].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print("Error loading data: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct PropertyRow: View {
    let property: Property
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(property.thumbnailName)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                .cornerRadius(8)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(property.address)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text("Type: \(property.type)")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                Text("Price: \(property.price)")
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
            .padding(.leading, 8)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct WatchListView: View {
    @Binding var watchList: [Property]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(watchList) { property in
                PropertyRow(property: property)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteProperty) // If you want to support deletion
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            // Handle tap gesture for selecting a property
            // You can navigate to property details view here
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteProperty(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        watchList.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}
```

properties.json code file:

```
[
    {
        "address": "10 Main Street, Cairns, Qld",
        "imageName": "PropertyResources/house1.jpeg",
        "thumbnailName": "PropertyResources/thumbnail_house1.jpeg",
        "type": "House",
        "price": "450,000"
    },
    {
        "address": "20 Elm Avenue, Sydney, NSW",
        "imageName": "PropertyResources/house2.jpg",
        "thumbnailName": "PropertyResources/thumbnail_house2.jpg",
        "type": "House",
        "price": "550,000"
    },
    {
        "address": "30 Beach Road, Gold Coast, Qld",
        "imageName": "PropertyResources/unit1.jpg",
        "thumbnailName": "PropertyResources/thumbnail_unit1.jpg",
        "type": "Unit",
        "price": "350,000"
    },
    {
        "address": "40 Park Street, Melbourne, VIC",
        "imageName": "PropertyResources/unit2.jpg",
        "thumbnailName": "PropertyResources/thumbnail_unit2.jpg",
        "type": "Unit",
        "price": "420,000"
    },
    {
        "address": "50 Green Avenue, Perth, WA",
        "imageName": "PropertyResources/land1.jpg",
        "thumbnailName": "PropertyResources/thumbnail_land1.jpg",
        "type": "Land",
        "price": "200,000"
    },
    {
        "address": "60 Lakeview Terrace, Brisbane, Qld",
        "imageName": "PropertyResources/house3.jpg",
        "thumbnailName": "PropertyResources/thumbnail_house3.jpg",
        "type": "House",
        "price": "600,000"
    },
    {
        "address": "70 High Street, Adelaide, SA",
        "imageName": "PropertyResources/land2.jpg",
        "thumbnailName": "PropertyResources/thumbnail_land2.jpg",
        "type": "Land",
        "price": "250,000"
    },
    {
        "address": "80 Oak Drive, Hobart, TAS",
        "imageName": "PropertyResources/house4.jpg",
        "thumbnailName": "PropertyResources/thumbnail_house4.jpg",
        "type": "House",
        "price": "700,000"
    },
    {
        "address": "90 Mountain View, Darwin, NT",
        "imageName": "PropertyResources/unit3.jpg",
        "thumbnailName": "PropertyResources/thumbnail_unit3.jpg",
        "type": "Unit",
        "price": "380,000"
    },
    {
        "address": "100 River Road, Canberra, ACT",
        "imageName": "PropertyResources/land3.jpg",
        "thumbnailName": "PropertyResources/thumbnail_land3.jpg",
        "type": "Land",
        "price": "300,000"
    }
]
```

Error:

```
No image named 'PropertyResources/thumbnail_land1.jpg' found in asset catalog for /Users/deepak/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6216FFC9-2B38-4813-BC46-9C7478C0C5C2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E258BA50-CB0D-4C08-AAB5-47A399ECDF45/Property List.app
```

its coming for all the images

We have download the image from google images and save them in the folder

Comment: That use AsyncImage and provide a complete URL

Comment: _"...save them in the folder"_, what folder is that?

Comment: If you have a directory called `PropertyResources` in your project that contains
 all the images, then to access them, drag this directory into your `Assets.xcassets`.
 
 In your code, just use the name of the image without the `.jpeg` extension.
 For example, use `thumbnail_house1` instead of `PropertyResources/thumbnail_house1.jpeg`
 So the easy way to do this, is to restructure your json data.